# hasOne with two join operator for one table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a problem with ORM of Laravel 6.x, let's see

I have two tables like:

**groups** : id, name, ....

**groups_tree_paths** : ancestor (group_id), descendant (group_id), ...

The problem is  2 groups will be have one groups_tree_path like:

**group 1**: '1', 'group_name_1', ....

**group 2**: '2, 'group_name_2', ....

**group_tree_paths**: 'id_group_1', 'id_group_2', ....

So how way can i get group and always return group_tree_path like :

**group 1, group_three_path**

**group 2, group_three_path**

When call : **Group::with('groupTreePath')** ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of defining a relation, you need to set foreign key which has to be unique for the parent model.
You need to set two relations for 'GroupTreePath' Model. One is ancestor and another is descendant.

```
//Group.php

class Group extends Model
{
    public function ancestor()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(GroupTreePath::class, 'ancestor');
    }
    public function descendant()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(GroupTreePath::class, 'descendant');
    }
}
```

Then call **Group::with('ancestor','descendant')**